# Redis disable persistence

Tags: redis

I need Redis to do a `flushall` everytime it crashes or is shutdown. I commented the "save" lines in the config file, but  can still retrieve all the data when I do `key*` after server restart.The setup does not include master-slave replication.

Any insight on this behavior would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the out put of **info** command

if **info** shows *maxmemory* being hold then it might be possible that some of the client are being writing and holding some output buffer. then check  list of connected clients using *client list* and kill all those clients.

Have a look on below links for more useful info:

[Even after flushall maxmemory shows the previous max value.](http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=654)

[Diskstore blocks after flushall](http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=556)